# How to deserialize a Serializable object from AsynchronousSocketChannel

Tags: java, serialization, nio, objectinputstream, nio2

To perform a deserialization, I need an `ObjectInputStream`. But we just use the `AsynchronousSocketChannel`, which cannot be converted to an `ObjectInputStream`. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `AsynchronousSocketChannel` to `InputStream` by `Channels.newInputStream(channel)`.